# Electric guitar online solo training class suggestions (paid or free)

Tags: electric-guitar, solos

I am a stackoverflow addict as a software engineer but not sure if it is appropriate to ask this question here. If not, please feel free to advise.

I play guitar last 15 years but never become a pro. I always play it my self and usually play acoustic guitar.

I play almost any chord to play a song, but I have to see the chords (cant just listen and figure out chords my self - very annoying)

But when I try to solo, I can play anything I hear in couple minutes (not talking about crazy fast solos) last year I start playing electric guitar with backing tracks and trying to solo on top of them. I am playing enough to have fun but also would like to improve my solo.

I am okay to purchase any online paid classes. There are bunch of facebook ads I see, but not sure which one would be really helpful (i am sure most of them would)

I am looking for a suggestion if there is any well known guitar solo videos outthere so I can buy and start practicing.

PS: I play couple times everyweek for an hour each session.

Again, if this question is not appropriate here, please help me where can I look for it. (Searching on google as “best online electric guitar solo training videos” would give you all the paid ads and it very generic title as everyone writes “best ever etc..” )

Comment: Are you hoping to play already existing solos, or being more capable of making up things on the fly?

Comment: @Tim - to be honest both... But I enjoy more with when I make things up which I know it takes more time to be pro with.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have personally worked on developing the guitar soloing courses included in the Musician Training Center software, so this suggestion is biased by that, but I'd say that you may find courses such as the Guitar Speed Trainer or the Guitar Scales Method pretty useful:

http://www.micrologus.com/courses